# Add new item to Dictionary dynamically using a variable

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm currently reading values from file and spliting them as parameter and value e.g. @id=7 becomes param = @id, value = 7.  I would like to use the param variable as a new key in the dictionary.  However, it is not working as expected.  I'm using the following code.

```
list1 = {}

with open('C:/Temp/file1.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

for line in lines:
    middle = line.find("=")
    param = line[:middle]
    value = line[middle+1:]
    list1[param] = value
```

In this code, the dictionary key and value becomes 7.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think your using a dict.

Comment: You're not outputting param, but list1[param].

Comment: Why not use  print("param = " + param + ", value = " + value) ??

Comment: You should not edit out the cause of your confusion from the question. As it is now, the accepted answer addresses a problem that is no longer in the question.

Comment: `param, _, value = line.partition('=')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are defining list1 as a dict `list1 = {}` then your print statement is incorrect.

```
print("param = " + list1[param] + ", value = " + value)
```

both `list1[param]` and `value` would be 7. since `list1[param]` would give you the value of it's contents and not it's key.

Try looking at the dictionary afterwards by printing it.

```
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to define your dictionary (`d` is a nice name). You can do it this way:

```
with open('C:/Temp/file1.txt') as f:#
    d = dict(line.strip().split('=', 1) for line in f)

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print("param = {0}, value = {1}".format(k,v))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this wasn't what you were asking for, but I would suggest to look at [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#configparser-objects). This is a standard way to use configuration files.